# How to play audio with base64 data URIs?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a problem, I got a base64 data URI scale up per time like image below. How can I play this? Thanks!

[image: Base64 Data Uri]

I had tried to use Howlerjs, but it just play for the the first uri when other coming and I tried to play with new uri but it's not effect.

```
    this.flagObs.subscribe((data) => {
      this.wav.fromScratch(1, 8000, '8m', data);
      this.wav.fromMuLaw();
      this.uri = this.wav.toDataURI();
    });

    new Howl({
      src: this.uri,
      html5: true,
      format: 'wav',
    }).play();
```

Comment: I mean :
"data:audio/wav; bas64, abc" 
"data:audio/wav; bas64, abcd"
"data:audio/wav; bas64, abcde"

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a few weeks ago. basically you have to convert the `base64` string to binary data.
i used this function

```
export function convertURIToBinary(dataURI: string) {
    let base64 = dataURI.split(';base64,')[1]
    let raw = window.atob(base64);
    let rawLength = raw.length;
    let arr = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));
  
    for (let i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
      arr[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
let binary = convertURIToBinary(audioBlobText)
let audioBlob = new Blob([binary], {type: 'audio/wav'}),
url = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob)
```

`dataURI` is the string you have.
PS - it's in Typescript, just take out the ': string' and you're good.
hope it works for you